# How to use JavaScript require in CQ5 (Sling)?

Tags: require, aem, sling

I have found that [Sling implements CommonJS require](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-1594):
But I have no idea how to use it for my case, by default `require("myLib");` searches for myLib in `/libs/foundation/components/primary/` folder (`require("/myLib");` searches in `/libs/foundation/components/primary/` as well), and I would like to use library from `/libs/myProject/..`.

I tried to use relative path, but it ends with error:

`Cannot resolve relative module name outside of a module scope.`

How can I setup scope, then?

---

According to what I have found in [code](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12451787/SLING-1594.patch), this error occurs when `thisObj` of called `require` does not map to any `ModuleScope`, but how can I set, or create new `ModuleScope` object in JS file?

---

Are there any docs, or examples of CommonJS Modules for Sling?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any docs unfortunately, and I'm not familiar with that feature myself, best might be to ask on the Sling users list, see http://sling.apache.org/project-information.html#mailing-lists